# English to formal predicate Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Convert the following into formal predicate logic. Define predicates as necessary. Then negate the predicate sentence. Push all negations to the closest terms.

***1) There are at least two people who everyone knows. Domain = {People}***

***2) Every student takes at least two classes. Domain = {people, classes}***

***3) All Students know each other. Domain ={ All people}***

My take in this....
for the 1) part is it valid to do something like this **∃∃∀z(, ,z)**. Where in my words i could be totally wrong.. there exist a pair (x,y) who everyone (z) knows.

For the 2) part i know that there has to be and existential quantifier and a universal. but I'm not sure how to write them down.

For the Last part 3) is it this **∀∀(, )** just on the basis that for all X there is a Y

Comment: People knowing each other should be expressed as a binary relation, not a ternary relation, so your solution to $1$ isn't right.  Also, you need to expressly note (in formal logic) that $x$ and $y$ are not the same person.  $\exists x, y \forall z P(x, z) \land P(x, y)$ is not a correct solution because it's possible that $x$ and $y$ are the same person.  Your solution to $3$ isn't quite correct because your domain is all people, but your statement is only supposed to be true of all students.  So you need a relation symbol to denote that a member of your domain is a student.

Comment: Could you help with the final solution? For the 3rd statement do you suggest using p(x) and q(x) is that what you mean? @RobertShore

Comment: I'd strongly prefer to provide hints.  For $3$, use $S(x)$ to denote "$x$ is a student."  And a minor tweak to what I wrote for $1$ will give you a correct solution.

Comment: Hey the hints help with the learning process. Much appreciated. I just ask for some patience if i ask a lot of questions. Any hint for the second part while i work on the other 2? @RobertShore

Comment: You'll need separate predicates to define "people" and "classes" and a binary relation to express that a person is taking a class.

Comment: So for 3 I came up with  ∀∀S(, ) where like you said S denotes x is a student.

Comment: @Elchavo18 No, you have to use $\mathrm S(x)\wedge \mathrm S(y)$

Comment: So would I keep the universal quantifiers and add those predicates^? @GrahamKemp

Comment: That says all people are students.  (Actually, it doesn't even say that, but that's the direction you're heading.)  You need a unary relation to express the concept of being a student and a different binary relation to express the concept that two people know each other.  Then you need to relate the premise that two people are students to the conclusion that they know each other.

Comment: $\forall u ~(\mathrm S(u)\to D(u))$ says, "Every thing, which is a student, shall doWhatever".  You need to say this for two students (and the *whatever* is that one knows the other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > 1) There are at least two people who everyone knows. Domain = {People}
>
> My take in this.... for the 1) part is it valid to do something like this ∃∃∀z(, ,z). Where in my words i could be totally wrong.. there exist a pair (x,y) who everyone (z) knows.

You must say: "There are some $x$ and some $y$ who *are not the same* people and every $z$ will know $x$ and know $y$."

You should also use a bivariate predicate such as $\def\op#1{\operatorname{\rm #1}}\op{K}(~,~)$ for "_ knows _"

$$\exists x~\exists y~\forall z~\bigl(x\neq y\wedge \op{K}(z,x)\wedge \op{K}(z,y)\bigr)$$

---

> 2) Every student takes at least two classes. Domain = {people, classes}

"For every $x$ who is a student, then there is an $y$ which is a class that is taken by $x$ and there is a $z$ which is *another* class that is taken by $x$."

You will need predicates for: $\op P(~)$ "_ is a people", $\op C(~)$ "_ is a class", and $\op T(~,~)$ "_ takes _" .

---

> 3) All Students know each other. Domain ={ All people}

"For every $x$ who is a student, then for every $y$ who is a student, then $x$ knows $y$."

Use predicates $\op S(~)$ for "_ is a student", and $\op{K}(~,~)$ for "_ knows _".

(NB: do you need to worry about whether $x$ and $y$ are the same people?)

Comment: Thank You! Your break downs help a lot. I think I got it from here.